# Get focused View in android

Tags: android, view

Is it possible to know the type of View which is currently focused. Means whether the View I taped on is either `TextView` or `EditText` or `Button` and so on.

Comment: You can use `instanceOf()`!

Comment: Right, but for that I need to write ClickListener for every View.

Comment: You can use single `ClickListener` for every `View`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just send the view to this method and you can check what type of View is it

```
 public void ViewType(View view){
   if (view instanceof ImageView) {
        // do what you want with imageView
   }
    else if (view instanceof EditText) {
        // do what you want with EditText
    }else if (view instanceof TextView) {
        // do what you want with textView
    }
    else if (view instanceof Button) {
        // do what you want with Button
    }
   }
```

so to check it you have to set onclick event for every view

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can .Call getCurrentFocus() on the required Activity. Also you can call getWindow().getCurrentFocus();